# Flex 4 now throws Security sandbox violation: file:///ProfilerAgent.swf

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flexbuilder

So I was doing some profiling on a Flex project and then went to go build a release build. Now when ever I export a release build it gives a runtime security error saying its trying to load the ProfilerAgent.swf

`Error #2044: Unhandled securityError:. text=Error #2048: Security sandbox violation: file:///Users/foobar/Documents/Adobe Flash Builder 4/.metadata/.plugins/com.adobe.flash.profiler/ProfilerAgent.swf?host=localhost&port=9999 cannot load data from localhost:9999.`

Error #2044: Unhandled securityError:. text=Error #2048: Security sandbox violation: file:///Users/foobar/Documents/Adobe Flash Builder 4/.metadata/.plugins/com.adobe.flash.profiler/ProfilerAgent.swf?host=localhost&port=9999 cannot load data from localhost:9999.

Even when I exit, restart, punch Flash Builder 4 it doesn't seem to go away. I tried manually compiling using the mxmlc via the command line and I'm still getting that error when it is running from my server. Any one have any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to locate `mm.cfg` in your OS according with [these instructions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fc9.html). Then check and comment (using `#` at the beginning of the line) lines starting with `ProfilingFileOutputEnable` and `PreloadSwf`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: There is no mm.cfg in my ~/ directory. I did find the one in the /Library/Application Support/Macromedia/mm.cfg but did not have anything about Profiling or PreloadSwf in it.

Answer (score 0):

Open up mm.cfg and make sure the following instructions are in configuration:

```
    ProfileFunctionEnable=1
    ProfilingOutputFileEnable=1
    RendererProfilingEnable=1
```